# METRO BUNDLER ERROR: Metro Has Encountered an error: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'transformfile')

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules, bundler, metro-bundler

I'm not sure why it is showing up like this, The problem occured on Bundler.js, and the error pointed to this line.

```
TransformFile(filePath, transformOptions) {
    var _this3 = this;

    return _asyncToGenerator(function*() {
      // We need to be sure that the DependencyGraph has been initialized.
      // TODO: Remove this ugly hack!
      yield _this3._depGraphPromise;
      return _this3._transformer.transformFile(filePath, transformOptions);
    })();
```

It might be important to add that I installed node via nvm.

Thank You!

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was solved by using lower node version. try `nvm use 16.14.0` (16.14.0 is the latest lts version.)

Comment: did not solve for me...

Comment: didn't solve for me either

Comment: It helped! I've used 16.19.0